# Is this Trigger design consider to be valid pattern

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm looking into a simple approach many Triggers into one.

Which approach will work best...

Example #1

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on SomeObject (after insert, before delete) {
  //in this case both insert/delete call the same class logic
  if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete) {
    // Call class logic here! 
  }

}
```

Example #2

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on SomeObject (after insert, before delete) {

  if (Trigger.isAfter) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
      // Call class logic here!
    } 
  }
  if (Trigger.isBefore) {
    if (Trigger.isDelete) {
      // Call class logic here!
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: following document will help you for best practices and understand the trigger frame work https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices

Comment: well worth reading Force.com Enterprise Architecture https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Library for superb code samples on trigger and many other patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your second approach preferable as you can allow the code to scale.

Also  you can delegate the actual trigger processing to a separate Service Class roughly like below.

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on SomeObject (after insert, before delete) {
    if ( Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert ) {
        Service.method1();
    }
    if ( Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete ) {
        Service.method2();
    }
}

public class Service {
    method1() { /* do stuff */ }
    method2() { /* do stuff */ }
}
```